# method with params

Tags: c#

I wrote this method:

```
static long Sum(params int[] numbers)
{
    long result = default(int);

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        result += numbers[i];

    return result;
}
```

I invoked method like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Sum(5, 1, 4, 10));
Console.WriteLine(Sum());  // this should be an error
Console.WriteLine(Sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15));
```

I want the compiler to shows an error when I call the method without any parameters (like `Sum()`). How can I do this?

Comment: It’s really hard to understand what you’re asking.

Comment: @Niloofar The code compiles and runs fine for me. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: may be you want to change the signature to `static long Sum(int first, params int[] numbers)` if you want that `Sum()` should not be allowed.

Comment: Matt Ellen; Likely a null reference on `numbers`

Comment: OP **wants** to have an error, he doesn't have it at the moment. He wants to have 1 mandatory parameter.

Comment: @Closers: Not a real question??

Comment: I think returning 0 would be okay, and not unexpected.

Comment: Just curious, what should Sum(1) return?

Comment: @Bfree, seriously? I think it is Sum(0) + 1

Comment: @Henk: My point is, that if no params is an error, then 1 param should also be an error.

Comment: @Bfree:  It's clearly a(n arbitrary) choice. I would allow Sum(). But.

Comment: maybe off topic, but why params parameter should be the last one?

Answer (score 13):

Extract first parameter out of `params` to make it mandatory:

```
static long Sum(int firstSummand, params int[] numbers)
```

Answer (score 8):

You could write

```
 static long Sum(int number1, params int[] numbers)
 {
     long result = number1;
     ....
 }
```

But then you would lose this option:

```
 int[] data = { 1, 2, 3 };
 long total = Sum(data);   // Error, but Sum(0, data) will work.
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Can't get compile time check using params...this will give you a runtime exception...

```
static long Sum(params int[] numbers)
{
    if(numbers == null || numbers.Length < 2)
    {
         throw new InvalidOperationException("You must provide at least two numbers to sum");
    }     

    long result = default(int);

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
         result += numbers[i];

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider two overloads:

```
static long Sum(int head, params int[] tail) {
  if (tail == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("tail");
  return Sum(new int[] { head }.Concat(tail));
}

static long Sum(IEnumerable<int> numbers) {
  if (numbers == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("numbers");
  long result = 0;
  foreach (var number in numbers) {
    result += number;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
Console.WriteLine(Sum(5, 1, 4, 10));
//Console.WriteLine(Sum());  // Error: No overload for method 'Sum' takes 0 arguments
Console.WriteLine(Sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15));
int[] array = { 42, 43, 44 };
Console.WriteLine(Sum(array));
```

Answer (score -4):

`params` requires at least one argument as its a syntactic sugar for `array[] arguments`. You need to:

```
Sum(null);
```

and handle the `null` case accordingly in your method.

Comment: No, `params` is fine with a call like `Sum()`. No `null` required.